# Inconsistent mouse look sensitivity (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sensitivity increases with decreasing framerate.
For example, with 200 fps I am able to do 1 turn, with 60 fps almost 5 turns.

I call this method from update. PlayerCamera is camera attached to player.

```
private void HandlePlayerLook()
{
    transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSensitivity
        * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    playerCamera.transform.Rotate(-Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSensitivity
        * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
}
```

I tried replacing Input.GetAxis with constant, which made player rotate consistently.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the problem was with multyplying it with Time.deltaTime. It looks like Input.GetAxis is already independent on framerate.

Comment: yes it is ([`Input.GetAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html)) though the documentation is really confusing ... in the example for some reason they **do** multiply it by `Time.deltaTime` ^^ But `the mouse delta is multiplied by the axis sensitivity and the range is not -1...1`

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this problem by saving the input in a vector 2 then normalizing it.

Comment: Pleasr provide a code example of your solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).